# Is a DBMS an example of middleware?

Tags: middleware

As the question is - is a DBMS an example of a middleware technology?

Comment: Middleware is any software (other than the OS - where certainly all softwares going to run above it and make use of it indirectly) that other softwares use to make benefit of any services it can provide. Examples include DBMS, Http Servers, Application Servers, ORMs, Messaging Brokers, and any other software that can be used by other softwares to make their development easier (in a way or another). @Jare Balme answer below is precise and concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a database system always is the **backend** part of an application's architecture.

An example for middleware would e.g. be `COM` or `CORBA`.

HTH.
Thomas

Comment: What does COM stand for in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. "Middleware" can be defined as software that sits between an application program and the basic services of the Operating System.  In general, Middleware abstracts those operating system services, and may provide additional functionality.  A DBMS fits this definition perfectly, proving a natural interface for efficiently storing, organizing, and accessing data.  The application program uses the DBMS API, rather than directly calling the operating system services for disk and/or memory access.  COM and CORBA are also examples of Middleware.

"Communication Middleware" is a specific kind of middleware that abstracts the IPC services of the operating system.  Communication Middlewares provide an API to perform inter-process communications (sending and receiving data), so the application program does not need to use the operating services to create and manage sockets, or pipes.  Examples of Communication Middleware include DDS, JMS, and Corba.

Comment: Nice and concise answer. I liked the part "Middleware abstracts those operating system services, and may provide additional functionality".